# How to calculate the light energy of a supernova?

Tags: light, supernova, flux

I have been given a distance, an average flux, and a time period. How do I find the light energy emitted of a supernova over that time period?

Comment: Your question seems interesting, but I feel like that a bit more details would not hurt, hence the close vote (which I am happy to retract once you edit). My main issue: Since you are mentioning a distance, you cannot be meaning the *overall* light emitted from the supernova. If so, you should also be having some kind of *observer area* (see [solid angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle)) over which you want to integrate.

Comment: Details can include examples of what you have studied to try to answer this. If you add context then answers can better address your needs. Also, you might apply [dimensional analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis) and see what happens, and while thinking about that, please mention the units of each of your givens, especially the flux. You may find a way to answer your own question in the process!